# How to use java to find json node by id and return that node?

Tags: java, json

I want to use java to find node by id and return that node, but now I'm only able to print out that node the return value is null. What's the reason and how to do it?

This is the json:

```
{
    id: '1',
    label: 'first',
    children: [
        {
            id: '2',
            label: 'second'
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the code I'm using now. The traverse json method using JSONObject is mostly taken from https://www.baeldung.com/jsonobject-iteration

```
package cn.velosoft.demo1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class GetTreeNode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json1 = "{\r\n" + 
                "    id: '1',\r\n" + 
                "    label: 'first',\r\n" + 
                "    children: [\r\n" + 
                "        {\r\n" + 
                "            id: '2',\r\n" + 
                "            label: 'second'\r\n" + 
                "        }\r\n" + 
                "    ]\r\n" + 
                "}";

        JSONObject jObject1 = new JSONObject(json1);
        String id = "2";
        JSONObject returnNode = findNodeById(jObject1, id);
        // I want the node to return to here
        System.out.println(returnNode);
    }

    private static JSONObject findNodeById(JSONObject jObject1, String id) {

        Iterator iterator = jObject1.keys();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            if (key.equals("id")) {

                String value = jObject1.getString(key);
                if (((String) value).equals(id)) {
                    JSONObject returnNode = new JSONObject(jObject1.toString());
                    System.out.println(returnNode);
                    return returnNode; //return value here doesn't work ...
                }
            } else {
                Object value = jObject1.get(key);
                handleValue(value, id);
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

    private static void handleValue(Object value, String id) {
        if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
            findNodeById((JSONObject) value, id);
        } else if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
            handleJSONArray((JSONArray) value, id);
        } else {
        }

    }

    private static void handleJSONArray(JSONArray jsonArray, String id) {
        jsonArray.iterator().forEachRemaining(element -> {
            handleValue(element, id);
        });

    }
}
```

The output is:

{"id":"2","label":"second"}
null

The first {"id":"2","label":"second"} is the System.out.println() in the middle, the second null is the print in the main function. Why it is null? How to do it?

Comment: **Why it is null?** -> Because your method `findNodeById` always returns `null`.

Comment: @ Oh sorry, I did write like @Ananthapadmanabhan 's answer below . It's still null...

Answer (score 0):

As @LHCHIN commented why are you not returning the `JSONObject` object from your method `findNodeById()` . When you find the key that match , the value must be returned . In your code you are always returning `null`.

```
private static JSONObject findNodeById(JSONObject jObject1, String id) {
    Iterator iterator = jObject1.keys();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) iterator.next();
        if (key.equals("id")) {
            String value = jObject1.getString(key);
            if (((String) value).equals(id)) {
                JSONObject returnNode = new JSONObject(jObject1.toString());
                System.out.println(returnNode);
                return returnNode //return value here
            }
        } else {
            Object value = jObject1.get(key);
            handleValue(value, id);
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

Comment: `JSONObject jObject1 = new JSONObject(json1);`In this statement , you are assigning json1 to the JsonObject while you are actually assigningthe json to the variable `json`.  Also, in method handleJsonArray , I couldn't get an iterator fron JsonArray.

Comment: How should this be fixed? I'm not clear on what's the problem with `JSONObject jObject1 = new JSONObject(json1);` The handleJsonArray method is copied from https://www.baeldung.com/jsonobject-iteration and this code runs fine on my Eclipse with JDK 11. I have pasted the full code.

Comment: @Nublia Ok okay , I was working on an older version of java(Java8).

Comment: btw, I suppose maybe it's the org.json version's problem. I have this in my pom.xml. Could you try this version?   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20190722</version>
   </dependency>